# Can Apple's Xcode IDE be used with a make build-system? If so, how?

Tags: mac, xcode, make, c++

I'm working on a large coding project and I'd like to try using Apple's Xcode IDE. Building the project depends on a fairly intricate system of makefiles (using mkcmake), and changing build systems is not an option. The few times I've poked at Xcode, it's appeared to have its own build system and Googling hasn't turned anything up.

Is it possible to use a make-based build system with Xcode, and if so then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can call `make` from Xcode. Apple has documentation for it in the "[Building Makefile Projects with Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/preparing/preparing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002849-BBCJABGC)" section of the "Porting UNIX/Linux Applications to OS X" guide on Apple's developer website.

Basically, it's…

File > New > Target > Cross-Platform > External Build System

…and you can probably figure it out from there.